# HTML5 form validation error pops up on jQuery .show() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am creating a multiple page HTML5 form. Each "page" of the form is in a DIV that is hidden/shown by a jQuery .hide() or .show() call when the appropriate BUTTON element is clicked.

The problem is: when showing subsequent pages, the validation check seems to be called automatically, and the error messages pop up on required field instantly before the user has had a chance to do anything. Is something accidentally triggering the form validation call?

Simple example:

```
<div class="page" id="page_1" style="display:block;">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
    <button onclick="$('#page_1').hide(); $('#page_2').show();">Next</button>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page_2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
</div>
```

Upon hiding page 1 and showing page 2, the validation error pops up on the first required field on page 2 instantly. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, all in the same form. But shouldn't validation only be called when the form is submitted? I haven't submitted the form yet.

Answer (score -1):

Put checkValidity Function on all input tags.
I have done it recently.

```
                function nextDiv(){
                var a = document.getElementById('ONE').checkValidity();
                var b = document.getElementById('TWO').checkValidity();
                var c = document.getElementById('THREE').checkValidity();
                var d = document.getElementById('FOUR').checkValidity();
                var e = document.getElementById('FIVE').checkValidity();
                var f = document.getElementById('SIX').checkValidity();
                var g = document.getElementById('SIX').value;
                er = document.getElementById("ERROR");
                var email = document.getElementById('ONE').value;
                var ec = checkEmail(email);
                var cp = checkPassword();
                if(a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && e == 1 && f == 1 && g!=0 && ec == 'true' && cp ==1){
                    $("#div_1").slideLeftHide();
                    $("#div_2").delay(1100).slideRightShow();
                    er.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }else{
                    er.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
```

This will return boolean value and check using javascript if else.
It will not show validation popup but if you will put required tag and pattern. than user will be visible of errors

Comment: THis is just an example. Follow it.